# How to write a sql query for insert multile column values in a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two column

```
Std_id     F_grade Course
1001       A1
1001       A2
1002       A1
1002       A2
```

now i want to take this in one column like below

```
Std_id      F_grade Course
1001        A1,A2
1002        A1,A2
```

I tried it with different way but can not make the correct result.So if any one can make the sql query for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT  Std_id
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(F_grade_Course AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Table1 
         WHERE ID = t.Std_id
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') F_grade_Course
FROM @Table1 t
GROUP BY Std_id
```